# Is it possible to generate energy from indoor draft by opening windows on opposite sides of the building?

Tags: electrical-engineering, aerodynamics, wind-power

Wind flow always generates naturally when I opening windows on the opposite sides of the building. 
Is it possible to put turbine on the way and generate electricity from that?
It could be optimising by building a tunnel and protecting walls for better indoor/outdoor temperature differences.

Comment: How fast is your wind moving?

Comment: The wind is not *generated* inside the structure.

Answer (score 2):

The two main considerations concerning wind power generation is the speed of the air and the duration of wind (air flow). The more of both, the better.

Trying to harness wind flow within a building will be difficult because the air flow will most likely be low (slow speeds) and the duration of flow may also be short, except on very windy days. Even a wind turbine with very low friction bearings would not be of much help.

Any electric generated this way would be small and for a short time period.

Answer (score 0):

Any natural 'wind' passing through the structure would be better harnessed by a turbine outside the building.

Any generated air currents (e.g. due to thermal differences etc.) will rely on external energy input (e.g. from the heating system), so, if you are able to create an airflow by opening your windows, and put a turbine in it, you will certainly recoup less energy than the heating system used to make the airflow in the first place. See the Second Law of Thermodynamics...

It *is* possible that in very specific circumstances, the heating effect of the sun could conspire to generate additional air movement without using up power on a heating system, but, in this case Solar-Thermal or PV Panels would be a *much* more efficient way to be generating energy...